# Throttling data not published to all active nodes

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, throttling

I have two physical nodes of api manager configured as explained in this guide. Two all components in one machine boxes behind a load balancer.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment#ConfiguringanActive-ActiveDeployment-Step4-ConfigurethePublisherwiththeGateway

Following is my configuration for the data publisher in api-manager.xml

```
 <DataPublisher>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ReceiverUrlGroup>{tcp://172.31.31.93:9611},{tcp://172.31.16.52:9611} </ReceiverUrlGroup>
            <AuthUrlGroup>{ssl://172.31.31.93:9711},{ssl://172.31.16.52:9711}</AuthUrlGroup>
            <DataPublisherPool>
                <MaxIdle>1000</MaxIdle>
                <InitIdleCapacity>200</InitIdleCapacity>
            </DataPublisherPool>
            <DataPublisherThreadPool>
                <CorePoolSize>200</CorePoolSize>
                <MaxmimumPoolSize>1000</MaxmimumPoolSize>
                <KeepAliveTime>200</KeepAliveTime>
            </DataPublisherThreadPool>
```

I have set an application with a application throttling policy of 10 Requests per minute. When I put both the instances behind a load balancer and fire requests, as long as both nodes are up, I am allowed to make 20 requests per minute. However if I bring one node down, it allows me to make 10 requests per minute. I suspect that traffic data is not being published by gateway to traffic manager.

What could be a configuration miss that I need to check to enable that? The only thing that deviates from the specified configuration in my case is that I don't point to single gateway node from both publishers. So both nodes have following APIGateway config in api-manager.xml

```
<APIGateway>
        <!-- The environments to which an API will be published -->
        <Environments>
            <!-- Environments can be of different types. Allowed values are 'hybrid', 'production' and 'sandbox'.
                 An API deployed on a 'production' type gateway will only support production keys
                 An API deployed on a 'sandbox' type gateway will only support sandbox keys
                 An API deployed on a 'hybrid' type gateway will support both production and sandbox keys. -->
            <!-- api-console element specifies whether the environment should be listed in API Console or not -->
            <Environment type="hybrid" api-console="true">
                <Name>Production and Sandbox</Name>
                <Description>This is a hybrid gateway that handles both production and sandbox token traffic.</Description>
                <!-- Server URL of the API gateway -->
                <ServerURL>https://localhost:${mgt.transport.https.port}${carbon.context}services/</ServerURL>
                <!-- Admin username for the API gateway. -->
                <Username>${admin.username}</Username>
                <!-- Admin password for the API gateway.-->
                <Password>${admin.password}</Password>
                <!-- Endpoint URLs for the APIs hosted in this API gateway.-->
                <GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
            </Environment>
        </Environments>
    </APIGateway>
```

Any help will be appreciated. My goal here is to ensure that irrespective of which gateway node the request is redirected to, the throttling should be consistent as defined in subscription across nodes.

Currently, it seems as if each node does an individual throttling.

Comment: Have you setup content synchronization mechanism?

Comment: Yes. I have setup the synchronization mechanism. It runs via cron every 5 minites. Does it need to be realtime? I can see throttling policies that are created being applied on both nodes. However I don't see the limits being shared between nodes. They independenly apply it.